# Как создать RTMP server на Delphi?

Tags: delphi, rtmp

Есть ли компонент для работы с этим протоколом?

**UPD.**

Задам вопрос иначе, как установить соединение с клиентом, если он делает такой запрос: rtmp://artgrek.ru/live

С компонентом вроде разобрался, TidTCPServer, запрос идет на порт 1935. Но приходит:

> ^�8�x��s��l.�[1�L���.��Vue��e�_dVdm��[�y��j�TV~���D��[�%�8F��#��*��l�����/k����$�$�,a�;��|��|�C�|P�quai#/�K~�g�}�%8�@H�cf�%i/�f�r+�P

Принимаю так `ReqString := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();`

**UPD**

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  ReqStrem : TMemoryStream;
  ReqData  : TIdBytes;
  ReqString : String;
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Execute');
  if AContext.Connection.Connected then
  begin
    if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size > 0 then
    begin
      //ReqString := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();

     ReqStrem := TMemoryStream.Create;
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(ReqStrem,
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size, false);
      ReqStrem.Position := 0;
      ReadTIdBytesFromStream(ReqStrem, ReqData, ReqStrem.Size);
      ReqString := BytesToString(ReqData, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
      ReqStrem.Free;

  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(ReqString);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Приходит вообще один символ

> Connect
>
> Execute
>
> Execute
>
> Execute
>
> Execute
>
> тут приходит символ типа маленькой L
>
> Execute
>
> ...

Comment: Так разбирайтесь с протоколом обмена. Судя по представленному содержимому - передаются не текстовые, а бинарные данные. Соответственно - readln здесь не подходит, нужно принимать или поток (TStream) или массив байт (TidBytes). А вот как принятое потом разбирать (какой байт или совокупность что означает) - здесь вам поможет разбор документации протокола обмена.

Comment: @kami добавил в вопросе.

Comment: И все равно вы преобразуете полученный поток данных в символы, хотя вам явно было сказано - не похожа получаемая вами последовательность на текстовые данные. Это бинарный протокол, а не текстовый. Читайте документацию http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/rtmp/pdf/rtmp_specification_1.0.pdf